# How to check permissions for each user in connected to a voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make a voice command in which you can claim a channel if there is no user who has the `Manage Channels` permission in the channel connected.

But how can I query that?

This is my current code:

```js
if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'claim') {
  if (!chmember.voice.channel) {
    await interaction.reply({
      content: '**Du befindest dich in keinem Voice Channel!**',
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  }
  if (chmember.voice.channel) {
    let channel = chmember.voice.channel;

    if (
      !chmember.permissionsIn(channel).has(PermissionFlagsBits.ManageChannels)
    ) {
      //Need to Check the Permission for every connected user in Voice Channel!
      if (
        !interaction.guild.channel.members.me.permissions.has(
          PermissionFlagsBits.ManageChannels,
        )
      ) {
        interaction.reply({
          content:
            "**Der Voice Channel gehört nun dir. Nutze '/voice name' um denn Name zu ändern!**",
          ephemeral: true,
        });
        channel.permissionOverwrites.set([
          {
            id: chmember.id,
            allow: [
              PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel,
              PermissionFlagsBits.Connect,
              PermissionFlagsBits.ManageChannels,
            ],
          },
        ]);
      } else
        interaction.reply({
          content: '**Der Owner befindet sich noch im Channel!**.',
          ephemeral: true,
        });
    } else
      interaction.reply({
        content: '**Der Channel gehört bereits dir!**',
        ephemeral: true,
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if any of the connected members have permission to manage channels, you can use the [`Collection#some()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=some) method. Similar to `Array#some()`, it checks if there exists an item that passes a test.

In your case, since [`channel.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=members) is already a collection of the members in this voice-based channel, you can use `channel.members.some()` to check if any of the members have the `ManageChannels` permission:

```js
interaction.guild.channel.members.some((member) =>
  member.permissions.has(PermissionFlagsBits.ManageChannels),
);
```

You could also simplify your code a bit by adding early returns:

```js
if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'claim') {
  let channel = chmember.voice.channel;

  if (!channel) {
    // you can return early, so the rest of the code only executes
    // if the member is in a voice channel
    return interaction.reply({
      content: '**Du befindest dich in keinem Voice Channel!**',
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  }

  if (chmember.permissionsIn(channel).has(PermissionFlagsBits.ManageChannels)) {
    // again, you can return early, so the rest of the code only executes
    // if the member has no permissions to manage channels
    return interaction.reply({
      content: '**Der Channel gehört bereits dir!**',
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  }

  let hasAnyonePerms = channel.members.some((member) =>
    member.permissions.has(PermissionFlagsBits.ManageChannels),
  );

  if (hasAnyonePerms) {
    return interaction.reply({
      content: '**Der Owner befindet sich noch im Channel!**.',
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  }

  try {
    // wait for permissions to be set
    await channel.permissionOverwrites.set([
      {
        id: chmember.id,
        allow: [
          PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel,
          PermissionFlagsBits.Connect,
          PermissionFlagsBits.ManageChannels,
        ],
      },
    ]);

    // ... and only reply if there is no error
    interaction.reply({
      content:
        "**Der Voice Channel gehört nun dir. Nutze '/voice name' um denn Name zu ändern!**",
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    interaction.reply({
      content: '**Fehler beim Hinzufügen von Berechtigungen aufgetreten**',
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  }
}
```